# Trying to install Ubuntu on Win 10 Machine, getting black screen after hitting "install"

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I've created 2 bootable USB drives for Ubuntu, one for Ubuntu 14.0.7 and one for 15.0.?. I've used one successfully to install Ubuntu on a HP laptop running Win 10; no matter what I do can't seem to install on my other laptop, an Aspire V3 running Win 10. I've tried using Universal Usb Creator (Pen Drive Linux) Yumi, etc. to no avail. Tried prioritizing Bios to Usb, still wouldn't work. What I get is the Ubuntu boot menu, but when I click any of the options the screen goes entirely black and I have to manually shut down. If you can help with this issue I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: There are no 14.0.7 or 15.0. Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 0):

On the boot menu, go to run live mode. Don't press enter, press C which lets you change boot commands. Where you see splash right after it type in "nomodeset" so it should look something like: ...quiet splash nomodeset --

try that and come back.